# Coloring a $(1\times n)$-grid - Did I count correctly?

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

**Q:** Given a row of $n$-squares, i.e $(1\times n)$-grid and a set of $N$ distinct colors, including *Blue*, *Green* and *Black*.

In how many ways can the grid be colored such that

1. no color is used twice?
2. no two adjacent squares have the same color?
3. both the first and the last square are green?
4. $k$-squares are green, $r$-squares are blue and the rest are black?
5. $m$-adjacent squares are green and the rest are any color except green?

with $k,r,m < n$.

**A:**

1. $N \cdot (N-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (N-n+1) = P(N,n) = \frac{N!}{(N-n)!}$
2. $N \cdot (N-1)^{(n-1)}$
3. $N^{(n-2)}$
4. $\frac{n!}{r! \ \cdot \ k! \ \cdot \ (n-k-r)!}$
5. Couldn't solve that one! :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems good to me, good job!
 
**Hint:** For the last one, pick the index in which you are going to put the green elements. Check that you can do it at $1,2,\cdots, n-m+1$ so you have that amount of possibilities, for the rest you still have $N-1$ colors and $n-m$ places to fill.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Shouldn't it be just $n-m$ places to fill though? So overall we have $(n-m+1) \cdot (N-1)^{n-m}$ options?

Comment: @9Sp Yes! Indeed.